# Mongo $concatArrays even when null

Tags: mongodb

I have a large set of documents that may have two arrays or one of the two. I want to merge them in a $project.

I am currently using $concatArrays but as the documentation says it returns null when one of the arrays is null. I can figure out how to add a condition statement in there that will either return the $concatArrays or what ever array is in there.

**Example**

I have:

```
{_id: 1, array1: ['a', 'b', 'b'], array2: ['e', 'e']}
{_id: 2, array1: ['a', 'b', 'b']}
{_id: 3, array2: ['e', 'e']}
```

I want:

```
{_id: 1, combinedArray: ['a','b', 'b', 'e', 'e']}
{_id: 2, combinedArray: ['a','b', 'b']}
{_id: 3, combinedArray: ['e', 'e']}
```

I tried:

```
 $project: {
   combinedArray: { '$concatArrays': [ '$array1', '$array2' ] }
 }

 //output (unexpected result): 
    {_id: 1, combinedArray: ['a','b', 'b', 'e', 'e']}
    {_id: 2, combinedArray: null}
    {_id: 3, combinedArray: null}
```

I also tried:

```
 $project: {
      combinedArray: { '$setUnion': [ '$array1', '$array2' ] }
 }
 //output (unexpected result): 
     {_id: 1, combinedArray: ['a','b', 'e']}
     {_id: 2, combinedArray: ['a','b']}
     {_id: 3, combinedArray: ['e']}
```

Comment: What you got after (1) and (2) ?

Comment: They are wrapped in a $project. I tried both independently.

Comment: I still don't understand what you have after (1) and (2). Error? Not expected results?

Comment: I edited to try and make it more clear

Comment: Use [ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) to pass an empty array

Comment: I did not realize I can stack these up like this. Lol now I have twice the same answer.... Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As documentation for [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) says

> If any argument resolves to a value of null or refers to a field that
>   is missing, $concatArrays returns null.

So we need to be sure that we are not passing arguments which refer to a missing field or null. You can do that with [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator:

> Evaluates an expression and returns the value of the expression if the
>   expression evaluates to a non-null value. If the expression evaluates
>   to a null value, including instances of undefined values or missing
>   fields, returns the value of the replacement expression.

So just return empty array if filed expression will not evaluate to non-null value:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project: {
          combinedArray: { '$concatArrays': [ 
              {$ifNull: ['$array1', []]},
              {$ifNull: ['$array2', []]}
           ] }
       }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this with the `$ifNull` operator:

```
db.arr.aggregate([
   {
      $project:{
         combinedArray:{
            $concatArrays:[
               {
                  $ifNull:[
                     "$array1",
                     []
                  ]
               },
               {
                  $ifNull:[
                     "$array2",
                     []
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
])
```

output:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "combinedArray" : [ "a", "b", "b", "e", "e" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "combinedArray" : [ "a", "b", "b" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "combinedArray" : [ "e", "e" ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do this with nested $cond, answer with $ifNull is better, but still posting my answer.

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate( [{
 $project: {
    combinedArray: { $cond: [ 
        { $and: [ { $isArray: ["$array1"] }, { $isArray: ["$array2"] } ] }, 
        { '$concatArrays': [ '$array1', '$array2' ] }, 
        { $cond: [ 
            { $isArray: ["$array1"] }, 
            "$array1", 
            "$array2" 
            ] } 
         ] }
     }
}] )
```