# Union 2 tables like it is a single entity, then sort, skip, and limit (Mongoose)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, union, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have 2 schemas, schema A and B like the following:

```
const A = new Schema({
  paymentId: Number,
  date: Date,
  ...data
})

const B = new Schema({
  paidId: Number,
  date: Date,
  ...data
})
```

I want to return records from both A and B like it is a single table, where I can get records from both A and B that can be used with `.sort()`, `.skip()`, and `.limit()` functions ideally.

I could just do a `.find()` on both tables, concatenate them, and manually sort / skip / limit, but I find that highly inefficient.

**EDIT**: To clarify. It shouldn't matter if both collections are related or not. All I want is to query from both collections like both are in one collection.

For example, if I have the following documents

```
// Documents in A
{ date: '2020-01-01', A_id: 1 },
{ date: '2020-01-03', A_id: 2 },
{ date: '2020-01-05', A_id: 3 },

// Documents in B
{ date: '2020-01-02', B_id: 1 },
{ date: '2020-01-04', B_id: 2 },
{ date: '2020-01-06', B_id: 3 },
```

Doing a query with the options `.sort('date').skip(0).limit(5)` should result in the following:

```
// Documents in A and B
{ date: '2020-01-01', A_id: 1 },
{ date: '2020-01-02', B_id: 1 },
{ date: '2020-01-03', A_id: 2 },
{ date: '2020-01-04', B_id: 2 },
{ date: '2020-01-05', A_id: 3 },
```

Comment: How are these documents related, is it by fields paymentId and paidId ? Is MongoDB query fine? Sample JSON document will be helpful.

Comment: @Mallik B contains an array of A's. But with the way I want to query them, it shouldn't matter if they are related or not. MongoDB query is fine.

Comment: thanks for providing a sample document. I understand with sample JSON documents. Please see my suggestion below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/55289023/3793648:

> Doing unions in MongoDB in a 'SQL UNION' fashion is possible using
> aggregations along with lookups, in a single query.
>
> Something like this:
>
> ```
>     db.getCollection("AnyCollectionThatContainsAtLeastOneDocument").aggregate(
>     [
>       { $limit: 1 }, // Reduce the result set to a single document.
>       { $project: { _id: 1 } }, // Strip all fields except the Id.
>       { $project: { _id: 0 } }, // Strip the id. The document is now empty.
>
>       // Lookup all collections to union together.
>       { $lookup: { from: 'collectionToUnion1', pipeline: [...], as: 'Collection1' } },
>       { $lookup: { from: 'collectionToUnion2', pipeline: [...], as: 'Collection2' } },
>       { $lookup: { from: 'collectionToUnion3', pipeline: [...], as: 'Collection3' } },
>
>       // Merge the collections together.
>       {
>         $project:
>         {
>           Union: { $concatArrays: ["$Collection1", "$Collection2", "$Collection3"] }
>         }
>       },
>
>       { $unwind: "$Union" }, // Unwind the union collection into a result set.
>       { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$Union" } } // Replace the root to cleanup the resulting documents.
>     ]);
> ```

More details are in the post above. Adding `$sort`, `$skip`, and `$limit` is just a matter of adding them to the aggregate pipeline. Many thanks to @sboisse!

Answer (score 1):

```
//Can I suggest, $merge to merge these two independent collections into another different collection 
//and then use aggregation to doing sort(),skip() and limit()
> db.version();
4.2.6
> db.colA.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f76d969975ec8826bbcaab5"), "date" : "2020-01-01", "A_id" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f76d969975ec8826bbcaab6"), "date" : "2020-01-03", "A_id" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f76d969975ec8826bbcaab7"), "date" : "2020-01-05", "A_id" : 3 }
> db.colB.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f76d969975ec8826bbcaab8"), "date" : "2020-01-02", "B_id" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f76d969975ec8826bbcaab9"), "date" : "2020-01-04", "B_id" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f76d969975ec8826bbcaaba"), "date" : "2020-01-06", "B_id" : 3 }
> db.colA.aggregate([
{$match:{}},
{$merge:{into: "colAB"}}
]);
>db.colB.aggregate([
{$match:{}},
{$merge:{into: "colAB"}}
]);
> db.colAB.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f76d969975ec8826bbcaab5"), "A_id" : 1, "date" : "2020-01-01" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f76d969975ec8826bbcaab6"), "A_id" : 2, "date" : "2020-01-03" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f76d969975ec8826bbcaab7"), "A_id" : 3, "date" : "2020-01-05" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f76d969975ec8826bbcaab8"), "B_id" : 1, "date" : "2020-01-02" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f76d969975ec8826bbcaab9"), "B_id" : 2, "date" : "2020-01-04" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f76d969975ec8826bbcaaba"), "B_id" : 3, "date" : "2020-01-06" }
> > db.colAB.aggregate([
... {$project:{_id:0}},
... {$sort:{date:1}},
... {$skip:0},
... {$limit:5}
... ]);
{ "A_id" : 1, "date" : "2020-01-01" }
{ "B_id" : 1, "date" : "2020-01-02" }
{ "A_id" : 2, "date" : "2020-01-03" }
{ "B_id" : 2, "date" : "2020-01-04" }
{ "A_id" : 3, "date" : "2020-01-05" }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I think you misunderstood my question. the `pmt` and `paid` are not linked by their ids. Furthermore, it shouldn't matter if they have relation to each other. All I want to query are the documents from both collections sorted by date. Please see my edit in the question for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for this! So I'd have to delete `db.colAB` afterwards? How efficient is having to $merge every time, then get only the first 20 records, and then deleting the collection afterwards? Is there any way to improve performance?

Comment: Also, I was recently made aware of the `$unionWith` aggregation, which is perfect for my use case. However this is only available on MongoDB 4.4, which my cloud provider does not support for my specific subscription

Comment: @edirchhans: for performance improvement, if you have a large collection you can create an index on a date and try to $match documents with the date. You can use explain to check your query ````> db.colAB.explain("executionStats").aggregate([
... {$match:{"date":{$gt:"2019-01-01"}}},
... {$project:{_id:0,
...            date:1}
... },
... {$sort:{date:1}},
... {$skip:0},
... {$limit:5}
... ]);````  This plan will use index scan instead of collection scan.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to use $merge to create a new collection? Seems your solution still needs to create the collection `colAB` which I would like to avoid if possible.